# When ran, the program adds a large section of highlighted text at the end?

Tags: python, docx

The point of the script is to break a block of text into sentences, and then generate a random number to see if the sentence gets highlighted or not. When the code below is run it cuts out all the individual sentences and pastes them at the end of the document. I am looking for the sentences to be replaced instead of added on at the end.

```
from docx import Document
import re
from nltk import tokenize
import Funtion
import random
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

doc = Document('raw.docx')

rawdata = (Funtion.gettext('raw.docx'))

sen = tokenize.sent_tokenize(rawdata)

senlen = len(sen)

p = doc.add_paragraph()

for indsen in sen:
    rng = random.randint(1,11)
    if rng == 8:
        p.add_run(indsen).font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW



doc.save('TTTCH.docx')
```

Comment: I don't know about the use of these modules specifically, but it seems like you are: 1) reading raw.docx, 2) adding a paragraph to the end of it, and 3) randomly adding stuff to that paragraph.  Where do you see this code doing any editing in place? - the fact that you are reading the same file twice seems suspect.

Answer (score 0):

The sentences are being added at the end because you call

```
p = doc.add_paragraph()
```

Which is adding a paragraph to the **end** of the document, and then you are calling

```
p.add_run()
```

Which adds a run to the **end** of the paragraph you previously created.

Instead you will need to access the paragraphs **already created** within the document instead of creating your own. Like posted at https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.paragraphs you access these like (for example):

```
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    # process paragraph in place
```

I imagine you would like to use the information at https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#paragraph-objects

Specifically:

```
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    text_being_read = paragraph.text
    # process text
    paragraph.clear()
    paragraph.text = "New stuff"
```